# Rebooting boots to EFI shell, cold boot normal

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, restart

I have a Zotac ZBOX-CI320 Nano, with Ubuntu Mate 16.10 installed on a USB-attached SSD.

When I shut down, and then boot up again, it boots normally, to Ubuntu. But when I restart, it shuts down, and then boots to the EFI Shell. My boot priority is set properly in the motherboard's UEFI. There are no other bootable partitions/drives in my system. I haven't had this problem previously, with a different install of Ubuntu Mate 16.10 on a SATA HDD.

Anyone have any ideas? Could this be a problem with Ubuntu? GRUB? Or is it a problem with my motherboard?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a hunch, but my suspicion is that you're running into problems with the USB drive not being detected by the firmware in time to be used as a boot device when you do a warm boot. You might be able to work around this problem by installing a boot manager (Ubuntu's GRUB 2, my [rEFInd,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) or something else) *to the internal disk.* With any luck, launching the boot manager will give enough time for the USB drive to show up and it will work correctly thereafter. In the case of rEFInd, if Ubuntu doesn't show up, you can hit the Esc key and it should appear.

Comment: That makes sense. I bet you're right. Unfortunately, my goal was to reduce noise by removing the internal HDD, so at the moment, I have no internal disks. I could move the SSD to internal, but I'd have to buy a different adapter (it's an mSATA disk). Thanks.